# js.erb file not rendering asset_url image

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, erb, precompile

In the easyautocomplete template in `js.erb`

```
template: {
    type: "custom",
    method: function(value, item){
        var src = "<%= asset_url('thumbnail/" + item.slug + ".png') %>"
        return "<img src='"+ src +"'/> " + value;
    }
}
```

When I remove the variable `item.slug` and just add an image name, the image shows up on the autocomplete box and the code that it renders gives the proper precompiled png name such as `"thumbnail/1-slug121b62cd876657fcb0b46c01750fe6bbb5c720cd5b744ef12363d0ff3bc0834e.png"`

But when I put the `item.slug` inside the code, it renders up `src="thumbnail/1-slug.png"` which fails to show the image.

I am not sure what is actually wrong with this. I believe its just a format thing, I tried changing them though but nothing works.

Comment: Can you try with interpolation instead concatenation `'<%= asset_url("thumbnail/#{item.slug}.png") %>'` or `'<%= image_path("thumbnail/#{item.slug}.png") %>'`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma It's showing me an undefined variable error when I do return '<%= image_tag("thumbnail/ #{item.slug} .png") %> and when scr='<%= asset_url("thumbnail/#{item.slug}.png") %> the code source just turn out to look like <img src="/thumbnail/#{item.slug}.png" />

Comment: What's item, where's being defined?

Comment: @SebastianPalma from the function(value, item) which i believe came from the easyautocomplete gem's template. item is an element from a list. the slug name comes out properly when  i do return "<img src='" + item.slug + ".png'/> "